# Selenium - StaleElementReferenceException (Chromedriver 80)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code worked before the Chromedriver 80 update, but now it throws a StaleElementReferenceException when the element is present in the DOM:

```
public static void WaitUntilElementNotExists(string clase)
{
    Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    webDriverWait.Until(x => !ElementsByClass(clase).Any());
    Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitDefinition.TimeOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `StaleElementReferenceException` to `webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes()` before executing `webDriverWait.Until()`